# Shall structured binding to a copy of a const c-array be const?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, structured-bindings

Consider this code ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Nmz-gN)):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

struct Ag{int i;int j;};
using  T = std::tuple<int,int>;
using  Ar = int[2];

const Ag ag {};
const T t   {};
const Ar ar {};

void bind_ag(){
    auto [i,j] = ag;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((i)),int&>);
    }
void bind_t(){
    auto [i,j] = t;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((i)),int&>);
    }
void bind_ar(){
    auto [i,j] = ar;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((i)),int&>);       //For GCC
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype((i)),const int&>); //For Clang (and standard?)
    }
```

A *structured binding* to a copy of a `const` c-array are declared *const* by Clang and *non-const* by GCC.

The behavior of GCC for c-array is consistent with the behavior observed for aggregate or tuple-like types.

On the other hand from my reading of the standard, I suppose Clang follows what is written. In [[dcl.struct.bind]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#1.sentence-4) *e has type cv A* where A is the type of the initializer expression and the *cv* is the cv-qualifier of the structured binding declaration. And the type of the initializer expression `ar` is accordingly to [[expr.type]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#1.sentence-1) `const int[2]`.

What should be expected? My opinion is that Clang follows the standard. On the other hand I feel the intent was that the behaviors for array, aggregate and tuple-like types were equivalent.

Comment: Isn't this note related: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#3.note-1?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86049

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The wording of the standard in [[dcl.struct.bind]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind) says:

> If the *assignment-expression* in the *initializer* has array type `A` and no *ref-qualifier* is present, `e` has type *cv* `A` and each element is copy-initialized or direct-initialized from the corresponding element of the *assignment-expression* as specified by the form of the *initializer*.

We have `auto [i,j] = ar;`, `ar` has array type `const int[2]`, and the wording of the standard makes it clear that `e` has type `const int[2]`. Thus, *per the wording*, each binding references the element type - which is `const int`. Clang is technically correct.

However, as Richard Smith points out in [gcc bug 80649](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86049):

> I think this is a bug in the standard. The cv-qualifiers of the array type should be discarded, as they would be for any normal auto deduction.

That seems right. When you write `auto x = y;` you'd certainly expect `x` to not be top-level `const`, but here we have a situation where it still is. I don't think there's a Core issue open for this yet, but there should be.

Comment: The cv-qualification _cv_ comes from the decl-specifier-seq ("`auto`") not the initialiser ("`ar`"), no? Unless it's saying that the qualifiers on `A` are merged into _cv_. But I don't follow why that would be the case; without a ref-qualifier, why would it want to maintain constness? It doesn't do that anywhere else.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It does - but `A` is an array of const, so `cv A` is still an array of const. I don't think we want to maintain constness, hence Core issue.

Comment: Mm, I could be persuaded by that.